# jvm crash due to using jnotify or any other reason

Tags: java, filesystems, operating-system, jnotify

friends please help my java program crashes when run. I am using Jnotify to monitor drives.
The error shown is

[image]

Comment: -1; Did you read the output - lines 2 to 5? Did you even try anything? What's the context, how do the relevant parts of your code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly says that there was an error while creating the table Fdrive because it already exists. Try dropping that table from your database (if possible) and run everything again.

You should pay a little attention to the error messages,sometimes they tend to be pretty self-descriptive.